# How to show/hide multiple elements in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am currently creating a type of menu that will contain sub-menus, when a menu item is selected the sub-menu for that particular menu item will appear and any other open sub-menu will be closed.

Each of the menu lists is displayed inline so that they sit next to each other with 3 in a line, the sub-menu will then appear directly underneath spanning the whole width of the page and push the rest of the menu down the page.

I am having trouble making it so that when Item 1 is pressed only sub-menu 1 shows, and so on. Currently when any item is pressed, sub-menu 1 will be shown.

Below is the html...

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="sub-menu 1">
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu 2">
        <ul>
            <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu 3">
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>   




<ul id="menu">
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>

<div class="sub-menu 4">
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu 5">
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu 6">
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Below is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu > li").toggle(
    function(){

             $("#buying-guide-homepage > li").animate({height:109},"slow");
             $(".sub-menu 1").slideDown("slow");

        },
        function(){

        $(".sub-menu 1").slideUp("slow");
        $("#buying-guide-homepage > li").animate({height:89},"slow");

        });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your html like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
     <li id='sub-menu1'>Item 1</li>
    <li id='sub-menu2'>Item 2</li>
    <li id='sub-menu3'>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="sub-menu1">
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu2">
        <ul>
            <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu3">
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>   




<ul id="menu">
    <li id='sub-menu4'>Item 4</li>
    <li id='sub-menu5'>Item 5</li>
    <li id='sub-menu6'>Item 6</li>
</ul>

<div class="sub-menu4">
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu5">
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu6">
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
        <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You could do:

```
$('div[class^="sub-menu"]').hide();
$("#menu > li").click(function(event){
    var id = event.target.id;
    console.log(id);
    $('div[class^="sub-menu"]').hide();
    $('div[class="'+id+'"]').show();

});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEKNM/

EDIT - UPDATE to hide the displayed menu on click

```
$('div[class^="sub-menu"]').hide();
$("#menu > li").click(function(event){
    var id = event.target.id;
    var div =  $('div[class="'+id+'"]');  
    if(div.is(':visible')){
       div.hide();
     }else{
       $('div[class^="sub-menu"]').hide();
       div.show();
      }

});
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEKNM/1/

Comment: Thanks Nicola, this has been a great help and is the sort of thing I was looking for, how do I make it though that if you press a menu-item again it will hide the respective sub-menu?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is the spaces you have between .sub-menu and the number. If you change your code to use `.sub-menu-1` `.sub-menu-2` and so on, I think you'll find it works.

The reason I think this is the case is because a space denotes applying a second class to that object in the DOM. So your `.sub-menu 1` is really two classes, `sub-menu` and `1`. You could also just select by `.1` and you'd get the proper element. If you try just doing `$(".sub-menu 1").html("CHANGED THE HTML");` you will see nothing changes. But if you change it to `$(".1").html("CHANGED");` or change the class name to `sub-menu-1` and then do `$(".sub-menu-1").html("CHANGED")`, it will work too.

Comment: Correct; but to prevent confusion, it's actually the descendent selector. So $('.sub-menu 1') is looking for "1, that is the descendent of .sub-menu". http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Good to know! I was puzzled about it myself, so I did some fiddling in jsfiddle.net to see what worked. Makes sense it's a descendent selector.

Comment: CSS: where !important means important!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dNcpJ/1/

There is probably a better way to select which menu to show, I just took the inner text of the top level menu as the ID of the sub menus.